# extracting the values from cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

Related to my work, I divided an image into a number of overlapping blocks and for each blocks dct coefficients are calculated. The dct coefficients of each block are stored in a cell-array. Next I want to retrieve the values form one cell. How can I retrieve the values from the cell?

Comment: Just use `{}` instead of `()` when adressing the element. E.G. `data{1,1}` returns the first cell-element value. You can use all commands which you can use normally, e.g. `:`, `end` or logical indexing.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer. I assume following your question: "*And am stored each dct coefficient blocks into a cell*". That you have e.g. 20 blocks each containing the dct of 100*100 pixel(double). So that your data is stored in a 20x1 cell array where each cell has 100x100 (double) entries. 
To adress a block (1 cell argument) use:

```
block_data=cell_data{k,l};
```

To adress one element of those elements inside your `block_data` use "normal" adressing:

```
element_data=block_data(m,n);
```

`k,l,m,n` are the indices of the respective data. I assume that your dct-block-data is numeric (e.g. double)